# Select min (datetime) and max(datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max, min

My data is like this

```
| id. | date. | datetime. |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 123  |  2022-01-02  | 2022-01-02 8:00:00 |
| 123  |  2022-01-02  | 2022-01-02 10:00:00 |
| 123  |  2022-01-03  | 2022-01-03 2:00:00 |
| 123  |  2022-01-03  | 2022-01-03 8:30:00 |
| 123  |  2022-01-03  | 2022-01-03 17:30:00 |
```

I want to select and order my data like this: (I want my result like this)

```
| id.  | date.  | in.   | out. |
|:---- |:------:| -----:| ---:|
| 123  | 2022-01-02| 2022-01-02 8:00:00 | 2022-01-03 2:00:00|
| 123  | 2022-01-03| 2022-01-03 8:30:00 | 2022-01-03 17:30:00|
```

I have been using like this

```
SELECT 
  [person_id] AS 'id.'
  , [date] AS 'date.'
  , MIN(datetime) AS 'in.' 
  , MAX(datetime) AS 'out.'
 FROM
tablename
GROUP BY
[person_id]
, [date]
```

Normal result: (I don't want result like this)

```
| id.  | date.  | in.   | out. |
|:---- |:------:| -----:| ---:|
| 123  | 2022-01-02| 2022-01-02 8:00:00 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00|
| 123  | 2022-01-03| 2022-01-03 02:00:00 | 2022-01-03 17:30:00|
```

to get my results but failed because using max(datetime) function was select the max datetime same date only but I want to select my max `datetime less than 05:00:00`. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Also avoid using more than one dbms tag: as long as each dbms has unique features, you'll probably attract people that won't be able to solve your problem and be wasting your and their time.

Comment: why are there two in date ant the 02.01.2022 but only 1 out?

Comment: you should also save when a row is in or out

Comment: Yes in one row , in and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've recreated your table in MS SQL SERVER and managed to get the result you want, see image, with the following query.

I've joined the table on itself. The first "main" table is used to show the result grouped by id and date. The second version of this table, the "sub" one, returns all the datetime records where the datetime is 5 to 29 hours more then the beginning of the "main" date that is shown. So then you only select the min and max one from the second version and there you go!

[image]

```
SELECT
    main.id AS 'ID'
    , main.[date] AS 'DATE'
    , MIN(sub.[datetime]) AS 'IN'
    , MAX(sub.[datetime]) AS 'OUT'
FROM
    worktime main
    LEFT JOIN worktime sub 
        on main.id = sub.id
        AND sub.[datetime] > DATEADD(hh, 5, CAST(main.[date] as datetime))
        AND sub.[datetime] < DATEADD(hh,29, CAST(main.[date] as datetime))
GROUP BY
    main.id
    , main.[date]
```

Comment: My code was like this but it select max(datetime) in same date. My last out datetime should be 5:00 am next day

Comment: Just remove the date column and group by. As date column doesnt really have a function.

Comment: "should be 5:00 am next day"  ????  Where is this time coming from ?

Comment: I have update my question..the max datetime should be less than 05:00:00 .. after 05:00:00 it consider new day for the date. Example like my question.

Comment: So the days you want to compare on one row go from 2022-01-02 05:00:01 to 2022-01-03 05:00:00?

Comment: Yup sir, you can refer my table in my updated question

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer accordingly. I'd to use a join on the same table so i could use the date from the original table in the where clause from the joined table

Comment: Can i see the sub table where you have join with main table?

Comment: its the same table as the main one (the one from the top part in the image) So in this example i've placed your data in a table "worktime". I've used that table twice, but because you need to know which version of the table you want to talk to i've called the first version (in this query as an alias) of worktime `main` and the second version of worktime `sub`

Comment: Ok tq sir for the perfect answer 

Comment: If in case i want to custom my time from 05:00:00 to less than 05:30:00.. where i will change it sir?

Comment: `DATEADD(hh, 5, DATEADD(mi, 30,(CAST(main.[date] as datetime))))` and `DATEADD(hh, 29, DATEADD(mi, 30,(CAST(main.[date] as datetime))))`

Answer (score -2):

SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE DateTime >= 'datetime you desired'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).